# lombok and @Valid not working together spring boot java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using lombok for generating Getter, Setter, AllArgsConstructor, NoArgsConstructor for User class and Doing some Validation with the help of @Valid annotation. **But for some reason no Validation I put on User Class is working for me**.

Below is the User Class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {


    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;
    
}
```

Below is the Controller Class

```
@RestController
public class ValidationController {

    @PostMapping("/validation")
    public ResponseEntity<User> validationtest(@Valid 
            @RequestBody User user) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
}
```

pom file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>validation</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Import used
import javax.validation.Valid

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

Comment: can you cross check the library from which validations are getting imported  ?

Comment: [Gurkirat Singh Guliani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15318227/gurkirat-singh-guliani)
I think so too

Comment: You must add error handling in your project:
please visit this [link](https://github.com/mjimani/SpringBootValidation)

Comment: Remove `@Validated` from the controller. And use `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency. If you have any validation API or hibernate validator as a dependency remove those and use the starter.

Comment: Can confirm, this (still) works. Adding the latest version of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation to my project was finally able to fix it.